# How to make output in 1 row for xml.builder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-builder

I want have output in 1 row text:

```
<A><d>n</d>Im newspaper text</A>
```

I used

```
xml.A { |t| t.d "n"; t.text! advert.newspaper_text }
```

In this case i have output:

```
<A>
  <d>n</d>
  Im newspaper text
</A>
```

How i can do it?

Comment: The default is [no indentation and no line breaks](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder/blob/master/lib/builder/xmlmarkup.rb#L170-L172).

Comment: Thx, its for all document, but i need use it in another case...
For example:
`<A1>First row</A1>
<A><d>n</d>Im newspaper text (Second row)</A>`

Comment: Then derive from their implementation and allow the option handled by your extended class.